# Sending linker flags to ndk-build

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to compile an android app that uses the jni.  I am compiling the native part of the app, and the linker fails with lots of errors like this one:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux- androideabi/4.8/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold:
error: /libsomething.a(flashloaderinfo.o): multiple definition of 'ResourceRequest::DispatchStatusEvent(HttpStatusResponse const*)'
libsomething.a(resourcerequest.o): previous definition here.
```

I want to link my app with this flag:

```
-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
```

to see what happens.  How am I supposed to specify that flag?  Does it go in my Application.mk file?  Or in Android.mk?

I tried

```
APP_CFLAGS =  -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
```

But that sets the flag during the build stage, not during the linking stage.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` in **Android.mk** or on command line.